# When CSS sprites would be good to use and when not?

Tags: css, xhtml, css-sprites

In what scenarios CSS sprites would be good to use and when not? Is it time saver or only server request saver?

I think bandwidth use will be same because image is same like ong big image but it's in a parts?

When and where use of css sprite is a time saving(in work) option ?

For navigation it's good for rollover pre-loading effect but not good for images disabled people?

What are other good usage which can save our time once and in future (if changes comes in design) both?

**Edit:** Sprites is only for css background so should we use images in background as much as possible to save sever request, is it good idea?

**Update:**

To implement takes more time then regular method and mostly client do not much worry about some slowness like http request. My question is can we save time in site making process and future maintenance of website using css sprite. or regular method is enough.

In nutshell my question is: **“can CSS sprites save our designer and xhtml css coder time (I'm not talking about server request)?”**

Comment: This forum is for developers, not for designers. Don't be astonished if answers were given in webdeveloper's perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- CSS sprites are best used for elements that have a fixed width and height. Otherwise, you need large empty spaces in your sprite image, which can (depending on file type) increase the size a bit.
- Due to the way different file formats compress images, sometimes a CSS sprite image will have a noticeably smaller file size than the total file size of separate images. That’s a nice bonus.
- As mentioned, sprites reduce the HTTP request overhead, which can help load time. I’ve never seen any numbers on the magnitude of this effect.
- Sprites will add a bit of time for your CSS developers. It shouldn’t affect your designers. But bear in mind that your developers code the site up once; the benefits of sprites apply every time someone looks at the site.

Comment: then should we use every fixed width image in background as much as possible to save sever request, is it good idea

Comment: Simply having an image as a CSS background image (as opposed to using an HTML `<img>` tag) doesn’t make any difference to the number of server requests. You save server requests by combining several images into one image (that’s what spriting means).

So, you have to decide which images to combine into one image. Coding and maintenance is easier if the images you combine into one are related, e.g. the navigation image example in your question.

Comment: yes i'm asking same "should i use combine every fixed width image in a big combined image then use as a background as much as possible to save sever request. or is it only good for rollover images?

Comment: “every fixed width image in a big combined image” — no. E.g. you wouldn’t want to put photos in a sprite. Photos are only likely to be used on one or two pages, so you’d be forcing visitors to every page on your site to download a photo they’d never see. Also, all **images** are fixed width. Sprites are good for images that will appear as a background to an HTML element that’s fixed width.

Comment: CSS Sprites would also save time as a graphic designer would supply as CSS Sprite for the entire site and this would reduce time spent administering images.

Comment: “a graphic designer would supply as CSS Sprite for the entire site” — man, I wish.

Answer (score 4):

It reduces the number of HTTP requests which will enhance site performance.

> CSS Sprites are the preferred method
>   for reducing the number of image
>   requests. Combine your background
>   images into a single image and use the
>   CSS background-image and
>   background-position properties to
>   display the desired image segment.

In [Minimize HTTP Requests](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/04/rule_1_make_few.html)

Answer (score 4):

CSS sprites are a time saver *because* it is a server request saver, as server requests are notably time-consuming. Using CSS sprites usually decreases your webpages' load/render time dramatically. There are times when they *cannot* be used, such as with background images repeating in two dimensions, but when you can use them, it's almost always worth the effort.

Of course you shouldn't sprite groups of images that are very big, especially if they're not very likely to be shown. Don't sprite an entire photo gallery into one big image, for instance =)

Other measures which amount to pretty much the same thing would be minifying, compressing and combining your scripts and styles into only one js file and one css file.

**EDIT**

With regards to your clarification, i'd say no, CSS sprites will always mean more work, never less, compared to just using the separate images as they are. I still wholeheartedly endorse their use, tho =)

Answer (score 2):

It will only reduce the number of requests but that will benefit both the server and the client.  The server will not need to handle as many requests.  The client, because it is limited in the number of parallel requests that it can make, will render faster as many of it's previous "requests" for the image will be served from its cache, allowing it to make the requests that it does need more expediently.

Answer (score 1):

Using sprites reduces the number of requests and thus also the network overhead. Loading a few sprite image is faster and uses less bandwidth even if the image data is the same (or even a bit more) than the individual images.

It needs a bit more work and some planning to combine the individual images into sprite collection images, so the development time is somewhat longer. The difference is less if you have it in the plan to start with rather than combining the separate images afterwards.

Any scenario where you have several same size background images that replace each other (or complement each other) is ideal for sprites.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have something like a dynamic photoshop PSD file in the back, then the designer's maintenance won't be an issue. But if it is a static file like PNG/GIF, then maintenance will take more time as you cannot control the individual images separately anymore.

Comment: but suppose if we or client wil decide to not to use some things from css sprite image then we will have to remove those parts from image to save bandwidth but in regular method we can just remove those images from content.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, sprites is a great idea. Use it for fixed width & height images that are less likely to be updated frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Sprites are always good to use. They help speed up the loading of web pages and prevent the blinking effect on navigation hovering.